# Issue reading Json format with Gson Java

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonforms

I need to turn a full string into Json format, the challenge is that within the payload there is a nested field which requires be read as Json likewise.

My java code look like:

- First I read the string :

```
    String payload
    ="{\"appId\":\"APP02\",\"employeeId\":\"789-33-3887\",\"name\":\"Paolo Ledner\",\"phonenumber\":\"757.910.0396\",\"beer\":\"Sierra Nevada Bigfoot Barleywine Style Ale\",\"company\":\"Schmidt LLC\",\"address\":\"{\\\"street\\\":\\\"Coralie Trafficway\\\",\\\"zipcode\\\":\\\"12291\\\"}\"}";
```

- Now I read my first JSON object:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
JsonElement jelem = g.fromJson(payload,JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jobj = jelem.getAsJsonObject();
```

This return properly the Json object but I can't read the keys from the nested field `address`, then I need to read the content of this field , turn it into string and according to my logic then apply the same approach to get the Json format and read the keys I need, here is this step:

```
String address = jobj.get("address").toString().substring(1,jobj.get("address").toString().length()-1);
JsonElement jeaddress = g.fromJson(address, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jaddress = jeaddress.getAsJsonObject();

System.out.println(jaddress.get("zipcode"));
```

*Issues*:

The string `address` returns properly `{\"street\":\"Coralie Trafficway\",\"zipcode\":\"12291\"}` but then when I try to print jaddress.zipcode I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1
>   column 2 path $.  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:902)     at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)  at
>   bncingestion.kafkaconsumer.validating_payload(kafkaconsumer.java:29)
>     at bncingestion.kafkaconsumer.main(kafkaconsumer.java:15) Caused by:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1
>   column 2 path $.  at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
>     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:513)    at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)    at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:738)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:714)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$35$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:910)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)     ... 5 more

An additional version of this transformation wihtout remove the `"` is here :

```
String address = jobj.get("address").toString();
JsonElement jeaddress = g.fromJson(address, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jaddress = jeaddress.getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(jaddress.get("zipcode"));
```

In this case the error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON
>   Object: "{\"street\":\"Coralie Trafficway\",\"zipcode\":\"12291\"}"
>     at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
>     at
>   bncingestion.kafkaconsumer.validating_payload(kafkaconsumer.java:31)
>     at bncingestion.kafkaconsumer.main(kafkaconsumer.java:15)

I appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: Why are you stripping the first and last character from the `address` text value? The text value of `"address"` is `"{\"street\":\"Coralie Trafficway\",\"zipcode\":\"12291\"}"`, which is parsed to the text `{"street":"Coralie Trafficway","zipcode":"12291"}`, so if you remove the first and last character, it is no longer valid JSON, since you just removed the `{}` braces that made it a JSON Object. --- Perhaps if you had **debugged** your code, e.g. printed the value of `jobj.get("address").toString()`, you'd have seen that for yourself.

Comment: I have tried even dont removing this two double quotes and happens the same man.

Comment: I have updated the post with that version and the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `jobj.get("address").toString()` formats the value (a `JsonElement`) as JSON, and since the value is a String, it adds quotes and escapes the content. Don't do that, i.e. don't call `toString()`, explicitly or implicitly, if you're after the *value*.

Replace line with `String address = jobj.get("address").getAsString();`
Also replace line with `System.out.println(jaddress.get("zipcode").getAsString());`